# how to disable compiler in magento2?

Tags: magento2

how do I disable the compiler in magento 2.0?

I have installed Magento 2.0 and then installed a theme "Porto" from theme-forest. But after installing the theme, when compiling, I got an error.

```
magento_user:/var/www/html/magento2$ sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 2 mins 418.2 MiBErrors during compilation:
        Smartwave\Filterproducts\Helper\Data
                Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $data. File: /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Helper/Data.php
        Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\FeaturedList
                Incorrect dependency in class Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\FeaturedList in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/FeaturedList.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image already exists in context object
        Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\FeaturedList
                Incorrect dependency in class Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\FeaturedList in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/FeaturedList.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image already exists in context object
        Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList
                Incorrect dependency in class Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image already exists in context object
        Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\LatestList
                Incorrect dependency in class Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\LatestList in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/LatestList.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 5
```

The theme vendor says I need to disable compilation. How do I do that in Magento 2.0?

I have looked for this in magento2 documents, and couldnt find any answers. i can disable modules using this command below, but which one is the compiler module

```
sudo php bin/magento module:disable Magento_xxxx
```

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated. My site is down now, and need to bring it up soon as possbile

Comment: The accepted solution is saying there is no way to disable the compiler. So how did you fix this issue?

Comment: the vendor provided an updated version, where i didnt face this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot disable the compiler. Why did the theme developer say to do that? Sounds strange.

In default and developer modes, the compiler is always enabled; generally, it's a good thing. In production mode, the compiler is disabled. But there is no way to disable the compiler in either default or developer mode.

Comment: For example, because our FE developer manages compilation himself for the theme. And if we upload assets then magento compiler fails to compile the less files, if we delete the less files than on static content deploy the compile is searching for non existing file...

Comment: Here is another example of a vendor providing faulty instructions for Magento 2.x. http://documentation.boostmyshop.com/embedded_erp/2_installation_or_upgrade.html says "Magento compilation musts be disabled" before installing their module.